# Why does this function print "undefined undefined" as a contact name, added with “new Object”?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I’m working on the JavaScript course at [Codecademy](http://codecademy.com). In this exercise, we’re supposed to create the function `add` which is supposed to add a person to the `contacts` array, then use prompts to get information from a user, after which we call the function `list` to print all the people in the `contacts` array to the console.

When I run the code below, it lists the two existing persons in the `contacts` array, but then prints `"undefined undefined"` for the person that I’ve tried to add with the prompts. When I print the length of `contacts`, however, it says `3`, so a person has been added.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var bob = {
  firstName: "Bob",
  lastName: "Jones",

  phoneNumber: "(650) 777 - 7777",
  email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
  firstName: "Mary",
  lastName: "Johnson",

  phoneNumber: "(650) 888 - 8888",
  email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = new Array(bob, mary);

function printPerson(person) {
  console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}

function list() {
  var length = contacts.length;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    printPerson(contacts[i]);
  }
}

/*Create a search function
then call it passing "Jones"*/

var search = function(lastName) {
  var number = contacts.length;
  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].lastName === lastName) {
      printPerson(contacts[i]);
    }
  }
};

var add = function(firstName, lastName, email, telephone) {
  contacts[contacts.length] = new Object(firstName, lastName, email, telephone);
};

var firstName = prompt("What is your first name");
var lastName = prompt("What is your last name");
var email = prompt("What is your email");
var telephone = prompt("What is your phone number");
add(firstName, lastName, email, telephone);
list();
```

Comment: The object that is the result of evaluating `person` is not what you expect and it has no properties named `firstName` or `lastName`: `new Object(firstName, lastName, email, telephone)` <-- this is not what you want. Try an object literal instead, as used at the start of the code.

Comment: Don't forget to declare variables (*i* in *search*). Also not a fan of function expressions where a function declaration will do the job (*search* and *add* functions). Lastly, use an array literal instead of the array constructor, e.g. instead of `var contacts = new Array(bob, mary);` use `var contacts = [bob, mary];`.

Answer (score 3):

To create a new object with properties, you have to give it both property name and property value for each property.  You were just passing a list of values to the `new Object()` constructor which does not make the type of object you wanted.

There are several ways to create a new object with properties, but in this case, it's probably easiest to just use the literal object declaration format `{name1: val1, name2: val2}`.  To do that, change this code:

```
var add = function(firstName, lastName, email, telephone){
    contacts[contacts.length] = new Object(firstName, lastName, email, telephone);
};
```

to this:

```
var add = function(firstName, lastName, email, telephone){
    contacts[contacts.length] = {firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: email, phoneNumber: telephone};
};
```

It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Ea7B5/

Comment: It should be `phoneNumber` instead of `telephone` (but your code works because `printPerson` doesn't use it). See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SvrLw/

Comment: thanks, it works, however the tutorial says that this can be done with the constructor new Object(firstName)...

Comment: @Michael: The `Object()` constructor takes zero or one parameters, so `new Object(firstName, lastName, email, telephone)` would be like saying `new Object(firstName)` as in your previous comment and it will not create what you seem to be expecting. The tutorial must have it wrong, unless you're quoting it out of context.